# Query MongoDB Collection Compression Settings?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

How can i query the settings for collection compression in MongoDB?
I configured WiredTiger as storage engine and as collection compression the zlib algorithm.

Here is a snippet of my configuration YAML file:

```
storage:
   dbPath: "/data/wiredTiger"
   engine: "wiredTiger"
   wiredTiger:
      collectionConfig:
         blockCompressor: "zlib"
```

Using mongo version 3.0.5.

Any help please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found the solution by myself.

use db.printCollectionStats()

in the output you will find the mentioned algorithm in the "wiredTiger.creationString" section.

```
"wiredTiger" : {
            "metadata" : {
                    "formatVersion" : 1
            },
            "creationString" : "allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=1),block_allocation=best,block_compressor=zlib,cache_resident=0,checkpoint=(WiredTigerCheckpoint.1=(addr=\"018181e4de542a6a8281e4f2e09da0808080808080e21fc0dfc0\",order=1,time=1440667794,size=8192,write_gen=2)),checkpoint_lsn=(2,25344),checksum=on,collator=,columns=,dictionary=0,format=btree,huffman_key=,huffman_value=,id=15,internal_item_max=0,internal_key_max=0,internal_key_truncate=,internal_page_max=4KB,key_format=q,key_gap=10,leaf_item_max=0,leaf_key_max=0,leaf_page_max=32KB,leaf_value_max=64MB,memory_page_max=10m,os_cache_dirty_max=0,os_cache_max=0,prefix_compression=0,prefix_compression_min=4,split_deepen_min_child=0,split_deepen_per_child=0,split_pct=90,value_format=u,version=(major=1,minor=1)",
            "type" : "file",
```

just look for block_compressor